# Grails, attribute in the relationship (join table)

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm

With grails how can I make an attribute on a relation in the join table.
like: Class A in relation with Class B as a role X. Class A in relation with Class C as a role Y.
And is it possible using postgresql to have class inheritance (a table for each class)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: To include extra data, you'll need to [create a custom mapping](http://www.grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML) that allows you to store more information than just the relationship.

Question 2: [Please read the manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.3%20Inheritance%20in%20GORM) which contains detailed information on inheritance.  It is possible to customize the inheritance to use multiple tables or a single table.  Also, [Grails 2.0 (in development right now)](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.M1/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew) supports even easier, automated inheritance right from the classes.

Comment: I've tried: static mapping = { table 'tablename' } but the table are not generated... How should be made the mapping?